# Historical or Extended test history

Tags: unit-testing, automation, allure, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Will allure provide a historical report of all the tests that have been run over a long period of time? I am open to other options as well. I am looking for a solution to having a bunch of individual test reports. Previously, Extent Reports has been used but would rather to have all the results in a centralized area that is available to all.

Update: we use Selenium, junit, cucumber, and java

Comment: Please clarify your question with more details, by sharing block of trial code. There are provisions in Extent Report for individual Test Report.

Comment: Do need just historical trends for overall pass/fail or access to actual test reports?

Comment: I would like historical pass/fail as well as the option to select individual test and display, runtime for test, pass/fail, possibly how many times ran

Comment: i have been looking into Klov but i am unsure if the historical report can be viewed by anyone within a company

Comment: Anyone in your company can open the link to Klov and view it. We have a dedicated box for it that our team uses to access it.  See the new url, it is now user driven so I am guessing all your users will now have to create an account to access.

Comment: @Karthik what does your team use for continuous deployment of the MongoDB?

Comment: Mongo and databaes in general are not a good CI candidates. Ours lives on a permanent VDI and managed by our database guys. We have a few projects that use the database so the DB itself is a sharded cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Klov.

1. [Docs](http://extentreports.com/docs/klov/)
2. [Demo](http://klov.herokuapp.com/)

There you have a "Builds" menu where you can see all the reports. 
I like it because:

- The testcases are updated in real time after execution
- I can track progress on different versions

What I don't like:

- Screenshots issue
- Description and Author are not displayed

Hope it helps!

Comment: Screenshot issue resolved, see comment: github.com/anshooarora/klov/issues/45#issuecomment-407963164